# Angular original array of objects gets modified when function should modify the new array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of products that is imported onto the add-product.component.ts

There is a feature where you can add the product onto a cart called basket

What the car.service will do it take the product and add it to and array called basketItems. If product already exists in basketItems array it should mutate that entry of basketItem.

For some reason both basket and products are mutating and it's causing the origin product display to change in price when only the basket should.

I'm new to Angular I'm not sure I'm passing a reference of that product when I run (click)="addToCart(product)" in add-product.component.html

[Product Page before adding anything to the cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCVFo.png)

[Product Page after adding something to the cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYTrM.png)

**add-product.component.html**

**Array of Products**

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
    <div *ngFor='let product of products' class="card mb-5" style="width: 20rem; height: 20rem">
        <img style="object-fit: contain; margin-top: 5%" height="45%" src={{product.image}} [title]='product.name' class="card-img-top" alt={{product.name}}>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{product.name}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{product.description | slice:0:60}}...</p>
            </div>
            <a style="float: left" (click)="addToCart(product)" class="card-link text-primary">Add</a>
            <p style="float: right">{{product.price | currency}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col">Count</th>
                    <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Description</th>
                    <th scope="col">Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor='let item of basket; index as itemId'>
                    <th scope="row"><button (click)="removeFromCart(itemId)">X</button></th>
                    <th scope="row">{{item.count}}</th>
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.description | slice:0:20}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.price | currency}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3" scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col">Total:</th>
                    <th scope="col">{{total | currency}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button style="float: right" class="btn btn-primary">CHECK OUT</button>
</div>
```

**add-product.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { products } from "../products";
import { CartService } from "../cart.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-add-product",
  templateUrl: "./add-product.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./add-product.component.css"]
})
export class AddProductComponent implements OnInit {
  // Array of products to be displayed on screen for the user to add to the basket
  products: object[] = products;

  // The basket is an array of items that were added by the user when they click the add button for that product
  basket: object[];
  total: number;
  constructor(private cartService: CartService) {}

  addToCart(item) {
    this.cartService.addToCart(item);
    this.total = this.basket.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price, 0);
  }

  removeFromCart(index) {
    this.cartService.removeFromCart(index);
    this.basket = this.cartService.getItems();
    this.total = this.basket.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price, 0);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.basket = this.cartService.getItems();
  }
}
```

**cart.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
@Injectable()
export class CartService {
  basketItems: object[] = [];

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {}

  addToCart(product) {
    // if product is already in the basket
    // FIX ME basket should mutate and not the product
    for (let i = 0; i < this.basketItems.length; i++) {
      if (product === this.basketItems[i]) {
        let originalPrice =
          this.basketItems[i].price / this.basketItems[i].count;
        this.basketItems[i].count = this.basketItems[i].count + 1;
        this.basketItems[i].price = this.basketItems[i].price + originalPrice;
        console.log("this should not mutate ===>", product, "but it does");
        return;
      }
    }

    this.basketItems.push(product);
  }

  removeFromCart(index) {
    this.basketItems.splice(index, 1);
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.basketItems;
  }

  clearCart() {
    this.basketItems = [];
    return this.basketItems;
  }
}
```

updated for accuracy

Comment: You edit items in service and expect products in component edited instead ?

Comment: Thanks for posting a detailed question! Can you clarify what are you expecting to see? You can edit the question with the expected result.

Comment: Did you try to debug the CartService?

Answer (score 0):

This returns a reference :

```
 getItems() {
    return this.items;
    console.log(this.items);
  }
```

And you assign it your basket :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.basket = this.cartService.getItems();
  }
```

So they both points the same reference. When you make changes on your cart service items you also modifying the basket.

If you want to avoid this behavior you can use sth like this

```
getItems() {
    return this.items.slice(0); // or [...this.items] a.k.a create a new instance every time
    console.log(this.items);
}
```

And for your edit :

```
if (product === this.basketItems[i]) { // you check exactly they have same reference
   let originalPrice =
   this.basketItems[i].price / this.basketItems[i].count;
   this.basketItems[i].count = this.basketItems[i].count + 1;
   this.basketItems[i].price = this.basketItems[i].price + originalPrice;
        console.log("this should not mutate ===>", product, "but it does");
```

So it doesn't matter how you modify the reference. They both get modified.

So you are round tripping same objects.
What you need to do is :

```
 this.basketItems.push({...product}); // insert new object everytime
 // and checking part should be
 if (product.id === this.basketItems[i].id) // they are not same object anymore you can not check reference equality.
```

Comment: I've updated the description. The basket should mutate and not the product that the user adds to the basket.

Comment: I've been passing the product object as a reference instead of a value. I fixed the issue by using Object.assign({}, product)